# Android number with shadows animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want a number like this (black colour is background, red and cyan are "shadows"):

[image]

It is in the center of the screen and its dimensions are approx 1/3 of screen's dimensions. I want to perform two concurrent animations, both animations wil be 1 second long:

1) Change the size from 100 % to 1000 %

2) Change alpha from 100 % to 0 %.

To display number like this, I can use:

1) TextView - but I don't know how to make two shadows

2) Image - I can draw the image in photoshop with sufficient resolution and display it in ImageView. However, I'm not sure if the animation with quite big image will be fluent, without any glitches, even on very low end Android device.

How would you create the number and perform the animation?

Comment: You should use SVG, VectorDrawable and then animate that

Comment: Great, this works exatly as I need.